# Segmentation fault in c code for ASCII art conversion

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, ascii-art

I am writing a program for converting a file from `PPM` format to `ASCII art`. Every pixel of the input image is converted to greyscale by calculating the average of red green and blue values ((red + green +blue)/3). The upgrade of the basic version is that I calculate the average of RGB in a window of size n*n, which would decrease the size of the image. The input file consists of three lines: first is the name of the file we want to convert, second is the name of the file we want to write the converted image to, and the third is the size of the window (`n`) the program must use by converting the image to `ASCII art`. I think I implemented everything I should in the program and it does compile, but when I test it, I get segmentation fault. Could anyoune tell me please where the problem is?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// convert the calculated greyscale to a character based on brightness
char method_of_conversion(int greyscale){
    if(greyscale >= 230){
        return ' ';
    }else if(greyscale >= 200 && greyscale < 230){
        return '.';
    }else if(greyscale >= 180 && greyscale < 200){
        return '\'';
    }else if(greyscale >= 160 && greyscale < 180){
        return ':';
    }else if(greyscale >= 130 && greyscale < 160){
        return 'o';
    }else if(greyscale >= 100 && greyscale < 130){
        return '&';
    }else if(greyscale >= 70 && greyscale < 100){
        return '8';
    }else if(greyscale >= 50 && greyscale < 70){
        return '#';
    }else if(greyscale < 50){
        return '@';
    }
}

int main(){
    char ppmFile[100];
    char outputFile[100];

    int n;

    scanf("%s", &ppmFile); //read the name of input file
    scanf("%s", &outputFile); //read the name of output file 
    // the size of a window of pixels you have to convert to ascii art character
    scanf("%d", &n); 

    FILE *input = fopen(ppmFile, "rb");
    FILE *output = fopen(outputFile, "w"); 


    char header[5]; //header = P6
    fscanf(input, "%s\n", header);
    int width, height, maxPixel; // max pixel is always 255
    // read the header from the ppm file
    fscanf(input, "%d %d %d\n", &width, &height, &maxPixel);

    // allocate place for array[width][length][3]
    int ***array;
    array = malloc(width*sizeof(int **));
    array[0] = malloc(height*sizeof(int *));
    array[0][0] = malloc(3*sizeof(int));

    int x, y;
    for (x = 0; x < width; x++){ 
        for(y=0; y < height; y++){
            array[x][y][0] = fgetc(input); //red
            array[x][y][1] = fgetc(input); //green
            array[x][y][2] = fgetc(input); //blue

            int greyscale;
            int i, j;
            // convert blocks of pixels to a character and write it into output file
            for(i = 0; i < width; i+=n){
                for(j=0; j < height; j+=n){
                    // greyscale = (red + green +blue)/3;
                    greyscale = (array[x][y][0] + array[x][y][1] +array[x][y][2])/(3*n*n);
                    char c = method_of_conversion(greyscale);
                    fprintf(output,"%c",c); // write the ASCII art directly in the output file
                }
            }   
        }fprintf(output,"\n"); // dont forget to go into a new line
    }

    free(array);
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are never checking the result of `fopen`. Or any other file IO function. So if your file format is a bit different from what you expect, it will fail and crash.

Answer (score 2):

```
array = malloc(width*sizeof(int **));
array[0] = malloc(height*sizeof(int *));
array[0][0] = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
```

Here only `array[0][0]` is allocated, for all other indexes no allocation happens. The following loop then tries to write to the indexes that got no memory allocated, leading to the segmentation fault.

Comment: Yes you can add additional loops that allocate all the required memory. Alternatively you could to it in the loops you already have, allocating memory for each array index before you read in the values.